# Looking for guidance/alternatives on ETL process on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, apache-nifi, amazon-athena

I'm working on an ETL pipeline using Apache NiFi, the flow runs hourly and is something like this:

1. data provider API->Apache Nifi->S3 landing
2. ->Athena Query to transform the data->S3 stage
3. ->Athena Query to change field types and join with another data so it be ready for analysis->S3 trusted
4. ->Glue->Redshift

I found GLUE to be expensive to send data to redshift, will code something ad-hoc to use the COPY command.

The question I would like to ask is if you can guide me if there is a better tool/way to do something better/cheaper/scalable, specially on steps 2 and 3.

I'm looking for ways, to optimize this process and make it ready to recieve millions of registries per hour.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting workflow.

You can actually use some neat combinations to automatically get data from s3 into redshift.

You can do S3 (Raw Data) -> Lambda (Off PUT notification) -> Kinesis Firehose -> S3 (batched & transformed with firehose transformer) -> Kinesis Redshift Copy

This flow will completely automate updates based on your data. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#create-destination-redshift). Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought the same first time I saw all the transformations from landing to trusted made by sql, change of datatype, time corrections, etc. It fits so well that it surprised me. Obviously I'm making some little json transformations before landing (on NiFi), but not more that partitioning, some JOLTTransform and parquet convertion. I feel good that noone said that this was a crazy way of transforming data. Will look into kinesis transformer to compare it to sql. The truth is that SQL let me be *more* platform independent, today is AWS, don't know in a year.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your data in partitioned fashion in s3.
Then use glue spark jobs to transform the data and implementing joins and aggregations as that will be fast if written in optimized way.

This will also save you cost as glue will process the data faster then expected and then to move data to redshift copy command is the best approach.

Comment: I could think on replace sql with sparkSql to paralelize functions, sounds great for an upgrade, I will need to spin up an EMR/EC2 cluster with spark, will look up the costs.

Answer (score 0):

Read AWS GLUE https://aws.amazon.com/glue/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc
AWS Glue is a fully managed extract, transform, and load (ETL) service that makes it easy for customers to prepare and load their data for analytics. You can create and run an ETL job with a few clicks in the AWS Management Console